# How can I create the following UI in Android to be used in the bottom of a View?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-view, android-drawable

I am trying to create the following UI for Android.
I want to try to put this UI only in the top or bottom of a View.

[image]

How Should I approach this problem.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried manipulating your XML element layout properties? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "make a sawtooth border" option as far as I know, so you can do one of these things:

Find/make the background image with the pattern you want and add it as a drawable background (or just apply it on the edges you want)

Generate this pattern in the app using lines of triangles. (But why tho)

Find a library that does it for you.